# Number of while loops iteration in a class as per user's wish in python

Tags: python, class, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Actually I am trying to make a simple program using python, where I want the user to enter number of records as per his choice. I specified a separate function in class `no_rec`, to first specify the number of records and then by using while loop to continue in loop as per number of times entered by user.

```py
class account:
    def pd(self,rno,name):
        self.rno=rno
        self.name=name

    def no_rec(self):
        print("How Many Records you want to enter: ")
        a=int(input())        
        x=0
        while(x<a):

            def inp_det(self):
                print("*************************Please Enter Records: ***************************** ")
                self.name=input("Enter Your Name:" )
                self.rno=input("Enter Your REG.NO: ")
                print("*****************************************************************************")

            def out_det(self):

                print("************************Your Entered Details Are:****************************")
                print("Reg.No: ",self.rno)
                print("Name: ",self.name)
                print("******************************************************************************")

        else:
            print("NO!!")

obj=account()  
obj.no_rec()
obj.inp_det()
obj.out_det()
```

but it is not running properly, can anyone please help me what to do?

Comment: You are defining functions but not executing them. define the functions outside your loop and run them inside like `inp_det()`

Comment: Don't do this: `print("*************************Please Enter Records: ***************************** ")` and this       `print("******************************************************************************")`! Do this instead: `print(' Please Enter Records '.center(78, '*'))` and this `print('*' * 78)` and be happier! :-D

Comment: Why are you redefining functions `inp_det` and `out_det` over and over inside a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things to look at here,

first you're defining the methods (functions associated with a class) inside the while loop, so no attributes are actually being modified, you're just redefining the functions over and over

the other thing is you're not incrementing `x` so the `while` loop never breaks because `x<a` always evaluates to the same thing

one more item (though this could just be about editing the post) is indentation, which really matters in python. i made a few changes just rearanging your code which should get you closer to where you want to be

```
class account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rno=''
        self.name=''

    def inp_det(self):
        print("*************************Please Enter Records: ***************************** ")
        self.name=input("Enter Your Name:" )
        self.rno=input("Enter Your REG.NO: ")
        print("*****************************************************************************")

    def out_det(self):

        print("************************Your Entered Details Are:****************************")
        print("Reg.No: ",self.rno)
        print("Name: ",self.name)
        print("******************************************************************************")

    def no_rec(self):
        print("How Many Records you want to enter: ")
        a=int(input())
        x=0
        while(x<a):

            self.inp_det()
            self.out_det()
            x+=1

        else:
            print("NO!!")

obj=account() 
obj.no_rec()
```

notice how inside the while loop we call the methods defined above using the `self` identifier.

this will not create a list of records however, it will overwrite the record `a` times for this you will need to look at creating a list of these items.

it looks like you are just starting out though and the list of issues could get quite long. i strongly recommend you take a look at [Automate the boring stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/). it's a really great resource for starting out and will explain a lot of the concepts you seem to be struggling with here

Comment: can you please tell me how to append records in def out_det() ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong with your code. First it's indentation. A minimal example of what you want to do is:

```
class some_class():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.counter = 0
        self.foo = 2

    def do_something_once(self)
        print('Something was done')

    def do_something_number(self, number):
        for i in range(number):
            self.do_something_once()
            self.counter+=1

my_instance = some_class(8)
my_instance.do_something_once()
my_instance.do_something_number(5)
print(my_instance.counter)
```

Some notes:

A for-loop is well suited, if you know the number of executions beforehand. So you don't run into the problem of forgetting to increment a counter.

Defining functions in a loop is not needed in this case and for a more complex case, it will save memory and execution time if you define a function once and just call it in a loop instead of redefining it in each iteration.

If you define a function inside another function, it will only be known inside the scope of that function, and you won't be able to call it from the outside unless you return the defined function. You probably don't want to do this in your example.

So, applied to your example, the answer would be:

```
class account:
    def pd(self,rno,name):
        self.rno=rno
        self.name=name

    def inp_det(self):
        print("*************************Please Enter Records: ***************************** ")
        self.name=input("Enter Your Name:" )
        self.rno=input("Enter Your REG.NO: ")
        print("*****************************************************************************")

    def out_det(self):

        print("************************Your Entered Details Are:****************************")
        print("Reg.No: ",self.rno)
        print("Name: ",self.name)
        print("******************************************************************************")

    def no_rec(self):
        print("How Many Records you want to enter: ")
        a=int(input())
        for i in range(a):
            self.inp_det()

obj=account()  
obj.no_rec()
```

To be able to retreive more than one entry, you need to store the entries in something more than a simple integer variable, like a list. Furthermore, you probably want to rename your variable from `obj`.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:

```
def out_det(self):

    print("************************Your Entered Details Are:****************************")
    print("Reg.No: ",self.rno)
    print("Name: ",self.name)
    print("******************************************************************************")




def inp_det(self):
    print("*************************Please Enter Records: ***************************** ")
    self.name=input("Enter Your Name:" )
    self.rno=input("Enter Your REG.NO: ")

    print("*****************************************************************************")


def no_rec(self):

    print("How Many Records you want to enter: ")
    a=int(input())        

    while(x>0):
        self.inp_det()
        self.out_det()

        x -= 1
    else:
        print("NO!!")
```

Refactor your code accordingly. This just a reference how you can solve.

Comment: That's even worse than OP.

Comment: This is just for idea not to replace the actual code.

Comment: This won't even work, because the indentation is broken.

Comment: And still, you are defining functions inside functions, which is most probably not what OP intended.

Comment: I am not defining functions inside functions, Its just indentation error. I just wanted to tell the ower to move functions to outer level instead of having them in while loop itself. May be you misunderstood it.